# Powershell - script to migrate test cases from TFS to Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to migrate Test Cases for specific project from TFS to Azure DevOps using script. However, it is picking test cases from all projects even though i have specified one project.

```
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"

$tfsSource="http://tfsportal.lionbridge.com/tfs/TFSCollection01";
$tpSource="VDB";

$tfsDest="https://liox-teams.visualstudio.com";
$tpDest="TestCaseMigrationTest";

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.dll"

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client')
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client')
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.0.1\Newtonsoft.Json.dll")

$sourceTpc = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($tfsSource)
[switch] $refresh
$sourceTcm = $sourceTpc.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.ITestManagementService])

$sourceProject = $sourceTcm.GetTeamProject($tpSource);

$sourceTestCases = $sourceProject.TestCases.
$sourceTestCases = $sourceProject.TestCases.Query("SELECT * FROM WorkItem");


$destTpc= [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($tfsDest)
[switch] $refresh
$destTcm = $destTpc.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.ITestManagementService])
$destProject = $destTcm.GetTeamProject($tpDest);

foreach ($tc in $sourceTestCases)
{

    Write-Verbose ("Copying Test Case {0} - {1} :- {2}" -f $tc.Id, $tc.WorkItem.AreaPath, $tc.Title)
    $destTestCase= $destProject.TestCases.Create();
    $destTestCase.Title = $tc.Title;
    $destTestCase.Priority = $tc.Priority;
    $destTestCase.State = $tc.State
    $destTestCase.Reason = $tc.Reason

    foreach ($step in $tc.Actions)
    {
        $destStep= $destTestCase.CreateTestStep();

        $destStep.Title= $step.Title
        $destStep.TestStepType= $step.TestStepType
        $destStep.Description= $step.Description
        $destStep.ExpectedResult=  $step.ExpectedResult;
        $destTestCase.Actions.Add($destStep);

            }
    $destTestCase.Save();
}
```

Comment: Were you able to migrate your test cases from TFS to Azure devops using the script above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to write a Where query while querying work item.

```
WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '" + teamProject.Name
```

You can add a Where **`project = '@Project'`** to the query to limit the scope to just that project. By first calling `BeginQuery` and then `EndQuery` you'll get a `workitem` collection for just the items you were looking for.

The easiest way to get the required wql query is to create a query in Team Explorer, then use file->save as (in edit mode) to save it to file. Open that file in Notepad to copy the query out of there.

Hope it helps.